# What is the difference between using annotation and using web.xml?

Tags: java, servlets, annotations

I'm studying about Java Servlet and I'm curious why Apache Software foundation got rid of `web.xml` and made the programmers use annotation. Is using annotation better than using web.xml? What are the differences between them?

Comment: Note that there are still some configurations that you cannot achieve with annotations.

Comment: There are a number of factual errors in the question. 1. web.xml was not removed, it remains fully supported in the latest Servlet spec. 2. The ASF is not the custodian of the Servlet specification - that is the role of the JCP and the Servlet expert group.

Answer (score 9):

There is no difference, annotations are just more convenient and prevents you from having bloated `web.xml` with hundreds of entries (in case of bigger application). It is also a part of [Convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) approach. Also note that you don't have to use annotations, you can still register your servlets in `web.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

There are benefits and drawbacks to using both XML and annotation based Spring configuration files. However, it doesn't have to be an 'either-or' type of decision.

There is a wider issue here, that of XML vs Annotation If your object model is only ever going to persisted in one way, then inlined meta-data (i.e. annotations) are more compact and readable.

If, however, your object model was reused in different applications in such a way that each application wanted to persist the model in different ways, then externalising the meta-data (i.e. XML descriptors) becomes more appropriate.

Neither one is better, and so both are supported, although annotations are more fashionable. More mature APIs like native Hibernate offer both, because it's known that neither one is enough.

Comment: What does this have to do with Spring?

Comment: Spring does works on the dependency injection for creation objects that takes the meta information about class from Annotation.Try reading tutorial on Spring Annotation But i think this is too early for you to start with that.

Comment: I think you've confused me with OP. `web-xml` and `Servlet` API annotations and Spring annotations are two separate things. Why are you even bringing up Hibernate? Your answer has nothing to do with `Servlet` annotations as it stands.

Comment: this is hilarious haha @SotiriosDelimanolis is the this month java stackoverflow MVP :D